# Error using Microsoft Access Database to create ASP.NET website

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a simple C# CMS system using a Microsoft Access database

This is my connection string in the web.config file

```
<add name="VirtualCMSConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|ASPNetDB.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDB"/>
```

I have used the "Access Provider" module found here: http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingAccessInsteadOfSQLServerForYourASPNETApplicationServices.aspx

The problem I am having is that when I try to create a Dataset with the dataset designing I recieve an error when I try to choose the connection string for the table adapter.

> **Failed to open a connection to the database**
>
> **"Cannot obtain provider factory for
>   data provider named
>   'System.Data.OleDb'**
>
> **Check the connection and try again**

Could anyone please help me on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the .vsi, extracted it, built the SampleAccessProviders.dll and added it to your project?

> Now that we have created the assembly
>   it's time to actually use it. Open
>   your Visual Studio or Visual Web
>   Developer Express and create a new
>   website. In the project you create a
>   new subfolder called bin. After
>   creation right click on it and choose
>   Add existing item... from the context
>   menu that appears. Navigate to the
>   place where the built assembly is. Add
>   it to the bin folder of the website
>   project. After that repeat the same
>   thing with the access database
>   (ASPNetDB.mdb) file but this time put
>   it in the dedicated folder App_Data
>   which is one of the predefined ASP.NET
>   2.0 subfolders.

Comment: Hi Mitch,
Yes I followed the tutorial to the letter.
I have a file named "SampleAccessProviders.dll" in my bin directory.

The only thing I did do was rename the coonection string from "AccessFileName" to "VirtualCMSConnectionString" but I updated all references to it in the web.config file.